# Facing issue while performing file reading operations in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-7

I am new to php . Currently as part of Migration activity we copied the existing php application to a new infrastructure where we are facing a strange issue.

**Problem Statement:**
From the php application,not able to read  any file and it is  not throwing any errors also. I used the following libraries and got the same behavior:

1. file_get_contents (This is the existing mechanism and I should use this one in the new infrastructure also)
   Below two, checked to triage the issue:
2. readfile
3. fopen (tried with fopen just to see whether able to open like `fopen($file, "r") or die(` ),but this is also going to die condition

**Issue Triaging**
Made the below *sample.php* and make it  available in my current server configuration. This is available by accessing through url (for e.g. https://myapplicationdomain/myapplication/sample.php). This php component is reading an input.txt which is in the same directory (actually this is the simulation of our problem)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // show errors
error_reporting(-1);
//set your own error handler before the call
set_error_handler(function ($err_severity, $err_msg, $err_file, $err_line, array $err_context)
{
    throw new ErrorException( $err_msg, 0, $err_severity, $err_file, $err_line );
}, E_WARNING);

echo "fopen url is";
var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));
try{
$file ='input.txt';

if(is_readable($file)) {
  echo "$file is readable \n"
} else {
  echo "$file is not readable \n";
}
if(file_exists($file))
{
$homepage = file_get_contents($file);
var_dump($homepage);
echo "content is $homepage  \n";
}else{
echo "file is not present \n";
}
}catch (Exception $e) {echo 'Error Caught $e';}
?>
```

Apache server is running using apache user and this user is having permission in the files and parent directories,
Following are the observations we got during triaging this:

1. When accessing through url for e.g. https://myapplicationdomain/myapplication/sample.php (i.e. through apache server).
   a. functions `is_readable` & `file_exists` are returning true.

b. `file_get_contents` is returning blank and when I did var_dump, it is returning 'Null'

c. Confirmed the value of `allow_url_fopen` and it is returning 1 which is true

d. No errors are getting logged in this case.

e. Changed the permission of the 'input.txt' to see the permission behaviour. In that case,proper error got displayed in `is_readable` it self.So through this way ruled out the possibility of permission issue and also confirmed the error handler implementation is working fine.

f. Changed the location of input.txt to outside folders . ie. home/apache_user/ or root directory. Still file read operations are failing.

2. Able to run the same php code independently. i.e `php sample.php` .In this case,it is working as expected and all file reading operations are working fine.

3.Checked all the below php.ini configurations (removed all the values in disabled functions for testing)

a. open_basedir => no value

b. disabled_functions => no value

c. allow_url_fopen => true

Checked all the posts ,but not getting any idea how to proceed further. Following are version we are using: PHP 7.3.5 , CodeIgnitor framework  and also configured php-fpm.

Comment: _" it is not throwing any errors"_ - I bet it is. Have you looked in the server error log?

Comment: I am not able to see any error logs in this case. I checked both the apache error logs and fpm logs

Comment: Note that a different user owns the process if you run a script via web server than if you run the script from CLI. On my debian/ubuntu machines, the web server is **www-data** but when I run via CLI it's **sneakyimp**. I am not sure what user would be in effect for PHP-FPM.  HTH

Comment: Yes, regarding CLI,I got..But I ran with apache user in both cases. Also to double check the permission issue (as I stated in 1.e) changed the permission of input file only to root user..In that case , failure happened in is_readable function itself.So that made me believe that permission is in correct place.

Comment: What is the error that's being thrown?

Comment: @Darren I know it seems to be strange for me ,but there is no error populating

Comment: It is returning  blank. When I checked var_dump it is returning null

Comment: You actually got a `null` when you var_dumped the file_get_contents result? According to the manual, any kind of failure should result in a `false` return value, not `null`.

Comment: Yes, it is returning 'null'. I also checked by accessing the below snippet ``` <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
var_dump(file_get_contents('input.txt'));``` and the out put is coming as NULL for var_dump

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding php library which apache was referring had some issues. Since it is a migration project and it is working fine in the current environment,copied the existing php folder (which was inside apache) and fpm binaries and configurations from the working environment to the new environment.Still not got any idea on exact root cause (as only read scenario was failing),but this got worked